# how to propagate mousedown event to sibling?

Tags: javascript, html

You've seen the 'in case of emergency, break glass' signs before.  Behind the glass there is a button to press to sound an alarm.   In my scenario, I am trying to build something like that, where the user can *break the glass* and then *press the button* with ***one*** mousedown event.  Let me explain...

I've a parent element [A] with two children.  The first child [B] is behind and occluded by the second child [C].

The second element [C] serves as a protective screen, preventing mouse move events from getting to the second element.  This is done by calling `stopPropagation` on those events.

When the user does mousedown on [C], that element should disappear and the mouse event should go its sibling.  I make the element disappear by setting its display to none.

However the mousedown event does not go to the sibling [B], it bubbles to the parent [A].  Subsequent mousedown events *do* go to the sibling [B].

How would I make the initial mousedown event on [A] go to [B]?  That is, as soon as the glass is broken [A], how to press the button [B]?

Here is an example:
https://codepen.io/jedierikb/pen/JLPJrm

Comment: I guess you mean that [B] and [C] are overlapping siblings but you want them both to capture the click event. That's also what I want to know.

Answer (score -1):

it's because events will bubble to highest element in DOM tree . 
i see that you already  prevent event bubbling on  mouse move ,so you just need to  add

```
     e.stopPropagation();
```

to the press down event handler

```
$c.addEventListener( 'mousedown', function(e) {
 console.log( 'the red button has been pressed' );
 e.stopPropagation();
 $c.style.display = 'none';
 ff = false;
});
```

don't forget to add the same bubble preventing method to button "b"